# How can I sort this Bubble Sort in reverse?

Tags: java, arraylist, bubble-sort

I've got my bubble sort to sort my objects (eventually). However, they are printing in ascending order instead of descending order. I'm aware I could use a Collections.Reverse on the array, as far as I know, but (and yes this is a sort of "homework") I can't use that.

```
private void bubbleSort()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < employees.size() - 1; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < employees.size() - i -1; j++)
     {
        if (employees.get(j).compareTo(employees.get(j+1)) > 0)
        {
           Employee temp = employees.get(j+1);
           employees.set(j+1, employees.get(j));
           employees.set(j, temp);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Basically what I'm wondering, is there a way I can change a minus to plus or a less than to a greater than and have it sorted the opposite way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line

```
if (employees.get(j).compareTo(employees.get(j+1)) > 0)
```

to this

```
if (employees.get(j).compareTo(employees.get(j+1)) <= 0)
```

and it will sort in the reverse order.

Comment: thanks, had changed that to a less than, never thought of less than or equal to. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can change your compareTo method implementation, and that way you don't have to tweak this code at all.